# Angular 2 - Adding click function to button in table cell

Tags: angular, html-table, click, cell

[image]
I am trying to add buttons into table as screenshot above.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <article class="content">
      <section>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table highlight">
            <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let head of heads">{{head}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let body of bodys">
              <td *ngFor="let p of body" [innerHTML]="p"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
```

Here is my .ts:

```
for (var i in this.products){

    var wp = this.products[i]; 
    var temp = [];
    temp.push("x");
    temp.push("x");
    temp.push("x");
    temp.push('<a class="tbl-btn btn-primary (click)="termsheetClicked()">View Termsheet</a>');
    temp.push('<a class="tbl-btn btn-primary">View Product Offering</a>');

    this.bodys.push(temp);
  }
```

However, termsheetClicked() never called.

Comment: This has to do with compiled code : `(click)` isn't valid JS ; it is compiled to `onclick` when you build your application (not true, but it pictures your the issue). 

If you want to do that, you will have to bind your component functions to the window and call them with `onclick`. Also, consider using `ngZone` to stay in the context of Angular.

Comment: @trichetriche I have change (click) to onClick, nothing happens as well. Any other reason that might cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative. Instead of adding the buttons from .ts, I have added the buttons through HTML as below:

```
<div>
    <article class="content">
      <section>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table highlight">
            <tr>
              <th *ngFor="let wpHead of wpHeads">{{wpHead}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let wpBody of wpBodys">
              <td>{{wpBody[0]}}</td>
              <td>{{wpBody[1]}}</td>
              <td>{{wpBody[2]}}</td>
              <td><button class="tbl-btn btn-primary" (click)="termsheetClicked(wpBody[3])">View Termsheet</button></td>
              <td><button class="tbl-btn btn-primary" (click)="termsheetClicked(wpBody[4])">View Product Offering</button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
```